# Library for Ethereum types?

Tags: data-types, typescript

Is there a library for Ethereum types, for tests written in TypeScript?

For example, an `address` type would be better to use instead of a generic string for Ethereum accounts.

Comment: Did you have a look at Typechain: https://github.com/ethereum-ts/TypeChain ?

Comment: Can you import types directly from TypeChain? I know that you can generate types for your smart contract functions and properties, but that's a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/) contains many useful types. For instance, this is how you would use the `Contract` type:

```
import { Contract } from "ethers";
...
```

I haven't yet found an `address` type, but it should somewhere in there.